# Would a multi-part GEMM tutorial showing how to get over 90% theoretical performance be interesting to anyone?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking about posting a multi-part GEMM tutorial explaining how to achieve over 90% theoretical performance on a CPU. Part 1 would be concepts and memory management, part 2 would demonstrate a C implementation for a particular microarchitecture, and part 3 would demonstrate the low level issues and show implementations in Intel assembly.

The purpose would be two-fold:

1. To serve as a tutorial, since I see that most GEMM questions end up with unhelpful answers like "use intrinsics" of "use -O3"
2. To ask questions of my own throughout from people that know more about specific issues, e.g., memory allocation, assembly instructions. I'm breaking 90% performance but OpenBLAS is breaking 97%.

Furthermore, would something like this get deleted from stack overflow? I wouldn't want to put the time in if it does.

PS - people with more reputation, feel free to add tags, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you want to post to a personal blog...and then a discussion forum. Multi-part tutorials are not a good fit for Stack Overflow's strict question and answer(s) format.

Comment: Each article would have to be formatted as an appropriate question and answer or answers (self-answers of this kind are fine). It may be difficulty to organize what you have to offer in that way, but deviations from that style will likely get trounced in a hurry.

Comment: I don;t want to post to a blog, although it wouldnt be a terrible idea to use a blog instead. But it wouldnt get traffic and it wouldnt help people as much as SO. Also if I post it in a QA format, it would probably be closed as well. I dont see "What are the basic concepts behind OpenBLAS GEMM" lasting very long.

Comment: SO is not the place to post "multi-part tutorials" unless they're properly written in Q&A format, as others have already said. It really doesn't matter what you want; if the post is not in that format, it will (and should) get closed quickly. The site guidelines are very clear (and specific) about being a question and answer site.

Comment: @matmul _'But it wouldnt get traffic'_ Good and helpful information will get traffic over time, no worries.

Comment: ' if the post is not in that format, it will (and should) get closed quickly' great initiative to encourage others to share useful knowledge versus enforcing rules to the letter.

Comment: I'd suggest doing it in more than three parts, where each part asks a single well-specified **question** rather than covers a single theme.  Both because I think this will work better---you are not the only expert on this subject matter---and because SO is unfortunately populated by lots of people who like making up rules and lots more who like enforcing rules they don't understand.

Comment: @tmyklebu I already posted but I'd like to hear your suggestions. I can always edit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984396/how-is-optimized-gemm-from-openblas-gotoblas-so-fast

Comment: @matmul: I say this as someone genuinely interested in what you have to say on this subject:  Your question is "too broad" and might be closed as such.  I'm not sure it's the sort of thing that will attract horrible answers, though.  You'd do well to post a sufficiently-detailed outline of an answer soon.

Comment: @tmyklebu I plan to leave it up for a few days to see if it gets deleted. If it doesn't I will start answering.

Comment: @matmul: Yeah.  I'd predict it gets closed in that time by the rule-followers.  Go post an answer at a similar level of abstraction to the question and I *think* it stands a better chance.

Comment: It would certainly be very interesting to me.

Comment: @Zboson I will come up with something to share with you and the other people that are interested like tmyklebu. It seems like the minimods over at stackoverflow are more interested in enforcing their rules (rather, their own interpretation of the rules) rather than learning.

Comment: @matmul: Yes.  What's scary is that they actually do more good than harm.  You'll probably understand this better if you take a look at the deluge of crap constantly pouring into the site and you take a look at how limited the crap-filtering tools are.  I'd suggest working with, rather than against, the site's sociology here; it's not that hard to put content like yours into a form that they'll accept.  (And this really is about form, not content.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is too long to fit in a comment, but I thought I'd give some constructive advice on how to format your contribution.

In your (now closed) question, you asked:

> How is the GEMM routine in OpenBLAS so fast? Specifically:
>
> 1. What are the concepts that enable GEMM to perform at near-peak speeds? How is data managed through the many layers of modern CPU
>      memory? How are the matrices cached and how does one determine optimal
>      caching parameters for a particular microarchitecture?
> 2. How does one implement these concepts for a particular microarchitecture in a high-level language such as C (without using
>      assembly just yet)? What optimization "tricks" are necessary at this
>      level? Can you provide code snippets to illustrate how the concepts in
>      part 1 translate to a portable code that operates are near-peak
>      performance?
> 3. How does one hand-optimize assembly routines for a particular microarchitecture? How does one decide what instructions to use and
>      how to order them? Can you provide illustrative examples? What is the
>      final result?

I count 11 question marks above, 10 of which expound on a broad and vague (but very, very interesting) question.  In some sense, they're questions at four different levels of abstraction---why is OpenBLAS fast, how do broad microarchitectural details inform programming, how does the cache work, and how do you write a fast MM kernel.

To my knowledge (I've never written a fast BLAS), some of these points are adequately covered in Goto and van de Geijn's "Anatomy" paper.  It's OK to reference that paper (and others) in your questions and answers.  It may even be beneficial to do so; people who aren't familiar with the subject matter but like casting close votes might take it as a cue that the question's a little deeper than it might at first appear.

It might be fruitful to handle point 3 like this:

Q:  I wrote the following blob of assembly code:

```
(blob of assembly code)
```

My understanding is that, on my Sandy Bridge Blah Blah Blah, provided all the data is in L1d, I should be able to run the following driver loop 1234567 times per second:

```
(trivial driver loop that runs surprisingly slowly)
```

But it only runs 12345 times per second.  What's going on?

A:  (why the code runs slow, how to fix it so it runs faster, what it looks like when fixed, and .)

Notice that this is a self-contained question about ricing out a piece of assembly code that just about anybody with the expertise, time, and motivation can answer.  The answer is also rather likely to be informative and educational to anyone willing to put in a fraction of the work the answerer put in.

You can handle some of point 2 in a similar fashion:

Q:  OK, I've successfully riced out a DGEMM kernel (link to kernel-ricing question).  When I try to use it in the following way on my Sandy Bridge blah blah blah, it goes too slow:

```
(self-contained program implementing and running a DGEMM using the fast kernel)
```

Here's the perf stat output on my box:

```
(perf stat output likely identifying the problem)
```

What's an L2 cache miss?  How can I hide the cost of these things?

A:  (Answer providing details on what's going on, why, and how to mitigate.  Contains a much, much better DGEMM.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the input. I will try it this way in the coming week. My concern with this approach is that (if you look at all my past questions) it will come across as disconnected, random bits of overly specific information. Is there a way to organize it in multiple parts so that the average user can follow? That is my goal. I disagree that some of the questions are very broad. There are very specific strategies for managing the way a matrix multiplication is handled, which are discussed in Goto but the explanations may not be accessible to some users, which discourages them.

Comment: The other half of this endeavor is that Goto only discusses high-level issues. Someone looking through the OpenBLAS source code may be completely lost trying to filter through hundreds of assembly routines to find out what is really going on behind the scenes. My plan was to illustrate these techniques so that anyone can pick it up and start writing their own code from scratch.

Comment: @matmul: Yeah, I'm completely lost when I look at the OpenBLAS source code.  That's why I really want you to do this. :)  I think linking to all the related questions is all you can do to make it seem coherent.  My overarching point here is that everything here is about the observable behaviour of a CPU.  Observable means you can scientific-method this up; write the code, form the hypothesis, test the hypothesis, and ask the question when your hypothesis is wrong.

Comment: We should start with the first question. I will need to think of a way to rephrase it, so it does not come across as "too broad" and gets closed by the flag bigots. My answer to question 1 will allow people to understand ALL of the OpenBLAS source code. 2 and 3 are implementation, which will be easy once 1 is complete. Using only memory management concepts from 1 (and not a single vector SIMD instruction, and with -O2) it is possible to obtain 40% CPU performance.

Comment: @matmul: You can't really start with the first question.  It will get closed by PHP programmers for being "too broad."  And it will attract "but the rules of your game are unrealistic" comments/answers/downvotes.  For some reason, lots of people here *like* VTCing questions when they don't know the answer.  Going bottom-up means that they don't really have a leg to stand on, even if doing so results in an artificial and disconnected presentation.

Comment: (I do appreciate that all of the questions are to some extent intertwined and that the best way to think about DGEMM may be top-down, since microarchitectural details that naturally manifest themselves at higher levels inform the structure of the lower-level parts of the code.  But getting this to fly *on SO* will be rather difficult.)

Comment: If we can take all the negative votes (almost all of which were made overnight, before all these comments) as a response to the original question "Would a gemm tutorial be interesting to anyone" then we see the problem. And if we note that the comment with the most +votes was 'if the post is not in that format, it will (and should) get closed quickly' we can see the problem better. People are here to mini-mod and score internet medals.

Comment: Other people are here to learn, though.  The mini-mods, as you call them, are rather useful for filtering out obvious bunk from the site.  They shoot down some false positives too.  You can either rail against them and their behaviour or you can recognise that they're here to stay, their behaviour isn't going to change, and they can be made to serve a useful purpose.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question a "multi-part GEMM tutorial showing how to get over 90% theoretical performance" would be VERY interesting, however, it's not a good fit for SO currently.

SO's filter lets through some really uninteresting question which are highly opinionated such as [do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) which is still in the top 20 question on SO (and #1 in the C tag). The best answer to this question comes from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Type_safety) not from SO which I think is a shame. But if you ask a question that requires some thinking such as 
[no-useful-and-reliable-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856227/no-useful-and-reliable-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c) it gets called a duplicate (I guess it's finally been reopened). Is anyone really surprised that after the OP wrote

> Maybe this is not the right place to discuss such philosophical questions. At least, most answers here are off the point. Is there a better place to discuss this?

that we have not seen another question from him?

But let me make a suggestion as to how you can integrate your tutorial into SO.  Setup a git repository at https://github.com/ for your tutorial and make folders for each concept you want to explain. Make a README.md file in each folder. Github uses almost the same markdown as SO (it's called [Git Flavored Markedown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown)). Reference the git repository in your profile on SO. Then answer your own question on SO [replicating-blas-matrix-multiplication-performance-can-i-match-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071622/replicating-blas-matrix-multiplication-performance-can-i-match-it) and summarize and reference your tutorial. I think that's well within the scope of SO and would be appreciated. I noticed that you made that question a bounty question and nobody answered it (it's a very difficult and interesting question - unlike the question about casting malloc) so if you know the answer please share it.

Comment: I like this suggestion. I do plan to answer this question very soon (hopefully this weekend when I have some free time). I have some questions of my own. Maybe together we can get beat 97%.

Comment: @matmul, that would be great to get 97%. I have been concentrating on getting high efficiency with multiple cores using AVX and FMA so my approach is a bit different for now. I just started testing on a multi-socket system and the efficiency is poor so that's another problem. But I would like to get back to optimizing for a single instruction set. Your tutorial would be great for that.